# Regular expression find string outside square brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I have following sample data. The end goal is to translate (to another language like say Spanish) on the fly data that's outside the square brackets.

Below code works for most the cases however it fails for the last data for obvious reasons when the brackets [] are inside the string.

So I am wondering how to write an expression which will only grab things which are outside the brackets. Complete opposite of what I am doing right now. Please keep in mind that there can be messages that don't have any square brackets at all. You can assume that opening bracket will always have closing bracket.

```
namespace RegExDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] data = new string[]
            {
                "[00:05:00] Insert buckle tongue [0/1 = 5.81mA]", 
                "Remove buckle tongue [1/1 = 5.81mA]", 
                "Move track forward",
                "Move track forward [MinCrt: 1.0, 0.1A, MaxCrt: 5.0] [MinPos: 450mm, 420, 520mm]",
                "Waiting before taking reading [500ms]",
                "Waiting [500ms] before taking reading"
            };

            var regEx = new Regex(@"\[(.*?)\]");
            foreach (var instruction in data)
            {
                var instructionsOnly = regEx.Replace(instruction, string.Empty).Trim();
                var newInstruction = "'This is now Spanish: " + instructionsOnly + "'";
                var newFinalValue = instruction.Replace(instructionsOnly, newInstruction);
                Console.WriteLine(newFinalValue);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("All done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Sample output]

Comment: Realistically you'd like to split the string using `@"(\[.*?\])"`. Then after that, loop the array, if it matches `@"^\[.*?\]$"` leave the element alone. If it doesn't, convert element  to Spanish. When done, join the array into a string.

Comment: Practically speaking, it's better to translate the entire string at once with placeholders for the non-translatable stuff because the word order can change in translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite what you asked for, but I'd recommend something like this:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegExDemo
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         string[] data = new string[]
         {
                                "[00:05:00] Insert buckle tongue [0/1 = 5.81mA]",
                                "Remove buckle tongue [1/1 = 5.81mA]",
                                "Move track forward",
                                "Move track forward [MinCrt: 1.0, 0.1A, MaxCrt: 5.0] [MinPos: 450mm, 420, 520mm]",
                                "Waiting before taking reading [500ms]",
                                "Waiting [500ms] before taking reading"
         };

         var regEx = new Regex(@"\[.*?\]"); // lose the parentheses
         var placeholder = "SOMETHINGTHETRANSLATIONSERVICECANBETRUSTEDNOTTOTRYTOTRANSLATE";

         foreach (var instruction in data)
         {
            var matches = regEx.Matches(instruction);
            string tmp = instruction;
            for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
            {
               tmp = tmp.Replace(matches[i].Value, $"{placeholder}{i:0000}");
            }
            var newInstruction = "'This is now Spanish: " + tmp + "'";
            for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
            {
               newInstruction = newInstruction.Replace($"{placeholder}{i:0000}", matches[i].Value);
            }
            var newFinalValue = newInstruction;
            Console.WriteLine(newFinalValue);
         }

         Console.WriteLine("All done");
         Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

I have some experience with machine translation services, and usually they leave all-caps word mashups alone.  But you could try a sequence of symbols or whatever seems to work with your particular service.

Comment: Few things:
1) `instruction.Replace(matches[i].Value, $"{placeholder}{i:0000}");` after the replace newly generated string is not stored/used
2) By loosing the parentheses from regex when the data has more than one set of brackets [] it will merge all data in to one string.

Please let me know if I misunderstood anything.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow either of your points.  This worked for me as posted.  Obviously the `var newInstruction = "'This is now Spanish: " + instruction + "'";` line is where the call to the translation service would go.

Comment: oh I see your point on #1.  Sorry, I'm thick.  It's fixed now.